# Bin Ranges using vlookup is not giving correct results

Tags: excel

I have a look up table below and I want o bin ranges. They are in columns A and B of an excel spreadsheet. I am using the formula =VLOOKUP(F2,$A$1:$B$11,2,1) to look up the range.

| Upper Edge | ROMI Range |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 0 to 100 |
| 0 | 0.3 to 0 |
| 0.3 | 0.2 to 0.3 |
| 0.2 | 0.1 to 0.2 |
| 0.1 | 0 to 0.1 |
| 0 | -0.1 to 0 |
| -0.1 | -0.2 to -0.1 |
| -0.2 | -0.3 to -0.2 |
| -0.3 | -100 to -0.3 |
| -100 | -1000 to -100 |

I am getting the wrong results for the following.

| Values | Using Vlookup | Expected Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | -1000 to -100 | 0 to 100 |
| 0.25 | -1000 to -100 | 0.2 to 0.3 |
| -0.15 | #N/A | -0.2 to -0.1 |

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Use the lower edge value and sort them in ascending order

Comment: Yes as mentioned above ^^^^ approximate match works when the the table is sorted in ascending order, if its in descending order, the VLOOKUP formulas stops working properly and you shall get a lot of N/A errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work as you have overlapping ranges. `0 to 0.1` and `0 - 100`. Also `0.3 to 0` is in the opposite direction.

Assuming you mean `0.3 to 0.4` and `0.4 to 100`, then:

[image]

To get the lower edge:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(C3,FIND(" ",C3,1)-1))
```

To get the lookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(F3,$A$3:$C$12,3,1)
```